# Sequelize: A is not associated with B

Tags: database, express, associations, sequelize.js

I have read all the documentation on Stack Overflow and Sequelize website.

My database have the correct foreign keys. I associated IMAGES model to CREATION:

```
Images.associate = (models) => {
        Images.belongsTo(models.Creations, {
        foreignKey: 'idImagesCreation',
        sourceKey: 'id',
        onDelete: 'CASCADE',
    });
};
```

In my controller I call like this

```
 list(req, res) {
    return Creations
      .findAll({
          raw: true,
          include: [{
              model: Images
          }] 
       }).then(creations =>{ etc...
```

I have tried with "as" including {as: 'Images'} in my model and in my controller but still have the same error :

SequelizeEagerLoadingError: Images is not associated to Creations!

I have doubts on '(models)' parameter, where does associate find the models ?
I import them in the index file of the models folder. Is this sufficient?
Or does the error come from another source?

Comment: (Aside: not getting help here in two hours is not a big deal when addressing volunteers. It is best to ask your question after making a solid personal effort, and then once it is posted, **keep on searching and trying things**, keeping the question updated with your latest findings. Remember that you're addressing volunteers, and note that as a result, not all questions get an answer).

Answer (score 1):

That's because as Sequelize says the models are not associated that way. You have the association from `Images` to `Creations`, but not from `Creations` to `Images`, so what you need to do is make that association like this:

```
Creations.associate = (models) => {
    Creations.hasOne(models.Images, { as: 'ImagesCreation' });//hasMany depending on your relationship
};
```

This creates a FK on `Images` with the name `ImagesCreationId`, now you do the second association.

```
Images.associate = (models) => {
    Images.belongsTo(models.Creations);
};
```

Now Sequelize knows the association the way you want.

I would recommed to do the migration so you have now the right association.

Comment: Of course that what i did first (a friend of mine suggest me that is redondant so i remove it)...but if i add it again it doesn't solve the problem. I still get the same message...its a pain.

Comment: is not redundant for Sequelize, you need to that  so Sequelize know which models and key need to look. On my experience I avoid using `foreignKey` and `sourceKey` I only use `as` that way when I do the includes I know for sure which association I'm refering and on DB the FK gets the name you use with the `as` attribute.

Comment: must i refresh something with sequelize and my models in command line or...i'm still getting the same error...i used as in Images model and controller.

Comment: I found inspiration on this link : https://lorenstewart.me/2016/09/12/sequelize-table-associations-joins/